# Duplicate packages react-native

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native, sdk

I have expo react-native project(the main one), and i create a pure react-native project to connect with android and ios sdks. This is why i created react-native-library-bridge. Between this three project i have dublicated react-native package.

My main project has react-native package in dependecies, for other react-native project i put react-native package to peerDependecies, but when i put peerDependecies to react-native, library functions did not recognize react-native package to parent one. this is why functions did not work.

this is main project's package.

```
  "dependencies": {
    "sdk-wrapper": "file:../RNWrapper",
    "expo": "^31.0.2",
    "expo-localization": "^1.0.0",
    "i18n": "^0.8.3",
    "i18n-js": "^3.2.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.11",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "native-base": "^2.11.0",
    "prop-types": "^15.6.2",
    "react": "16.5.0",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-31.0.0.tar.gz",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "^0.8.0",
    "react-native-keyboard-spacer": "^0.4.1",
    "react-native-render-html": "^4.1.2",
    "react-native-simple-markdown": "^1.1.0",
    "react-navigation": "^3.0.9",
    "react-redux": "^6.0.0",
    "redux": "^4.0.1",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "sentry-expo": "^1.11.1",
    "socket.io-client": "^2.0.4"
  },
```

this is RNWrapper's packages (when i write react-native to peer dependecies bridge function did not work) =>

```
 "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.8.3",
    "react-native": "^0.59.5",
    "react-native-rn-wrapper-library": "/Users/alicancelik/Projects/RnWrapperLibrary"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.4.3",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.4.3",
    "babel-jest": "^24.7.1",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.53.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.8.3"
  }
```

this is bridge packages =>

```
  "peerDependencies": {
    "react-native": "^0.41.2",
    "react-native-windows": "0.41.0-rc.1"
  }
```

I expected the work my all dependecies but i got react-native dublicate package. By the way i try to change node_modules name change but it alsa did not work.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to clean catch memory and reinstall node modules

```
rm -rf node_modules && npm install
rm -fr $TMPDIR/react-*
npm cache clean
npm start -- --reset-cache
```

It's work for me.